# Stack Exchange Redis transaction is never executed

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Trying to execute the transaction as below using StackExchange.Redis library v2.2.4:

```
...
var transaction = Database0.CreateTransaction();
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.KeyExists(key));
await transaction.StringSetAsync(key, value);
bool isCommited = await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
if (isCommited)
{
    Logger.Info($"{GUID} Transaction Key {key} SET in Redis");
}
else
{
    Logger.Warn($"{GUID} Transaction Key: {key} was NOT SET in Redis.");
}
...
```

However the transaction is never executed, meaning the debugger never hits the statement `bool isCommited = await transaction.ExecuteAsync()`

I've also tried the synchronous `Execute()` still with no success. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the transaction from executing by awaiting the async command. Refactor to await once the transaction has executed.

```cs
var transaction = Database0.CreateTransaction();
var stringSetTask = transaction.StringSetAsync(key, value);
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.KeyExists(key));
bool isCommited = await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
if (isCommited)
{
    await stringSetTask;
    Logger.Info($"{GUID} Transaction Key {key} SET in Redis");
}
else
{
    Logger.Warn($"{GUID} Transaction Key: {key} was NOT SET in Redis.");
}
```